# drf-yasg: How to change operationId?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger-2.0, drf-yasg, redoc

[image]

How do I change the name of the request that appears automatically in `redoc-ui` when using `drf-yasg`.

For example: In the image, you can see that that the request is named **`fid_data-entities_update`**, it is picking this up from the URL.

How do I override/rename it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [**`@swagger_auto_schema(...)`**](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html#the-swagger-auto-schema-decorator) decorator to override the [**`operationId`**](https://swagger.io/specification/#operation-object) spec as using **`operation_id`** parameter

```
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.response import Response
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema


class OperationIdOverrideAPI(generics.ListAPIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(operation_id="Your awesome name")
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response({"message": "ok"})
```

Comment: I tried adding @swagger_auto_schema(operation_id="Update data entity name") on top of def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs) 
I still don't see the change. Is there anything else I should do after adding that statement?

Comment: instead of `update()` method, use either `put()` or `patch()` method

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Is there any way I can attach it to the update method? Because we are using create, update, partial_update, list and destroy for our APIs.

Sorry for making it more complicated. But thank you so much for the response