# is there a way to provide custom names for my drf-yasg endpoints?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-yasg

i am implementing an API using django-rest-framework and using drf-yasg to document and name my endpoints
[every post method ends with create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruV5a.png)

i tried searching through the documentation and i cant find a way to do it

Comment: Use `@swagger_auto_schema(...)` decorator and set `operation_id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned in the comment, you should use the `@swagger_auto_schema()` decorator for your API in order to customize it. then set `operation_id` to change its name in swagger docs.

here is an exact example that'll solve your problem:
[drf-yasg: How to change operationId?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67295356/drf-yasg-how-to-change-operationid)